# int[] copy = data; // What happens when data is an array?

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

Will someone explain what happens, with a memory diagram, when you place

```
    int[] data  = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
    int[] copy = data;
```

in your program?

Does it simply create an array with the same length as the previous? I know they will not have the same values, but that is all.

Will copy receive data's address in it's first index?

Comment: I don't understand why I got negative votes, it was a serious question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No copying of data occurs, you're simply assigning a reference to an array to a new variable.

```
----------
| int[5] | <--- data
|   1    |      points at the memory address of your array object
|   3    |
|   5    |
|   7    |
|   9    |
----------
```

When you say:

```
 int[] copy = data
```

What is happening is this:

```
         ----------
copy --> | int[5] | <--- data 
         |   1    |      points at the memory address of your array object 
         |   3    |      "copy" also points at the same memory location
         |   5    |
         |   7    |
         |   9    |
         ----------
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan! This is exactly what I needed. I knew it wouldn't make a new copy, but I just didn't understand what exactly was happening.

Answer (score 4):

This is not making a copy at all.

Your two variables `data` and `copy` will point at the same array.

If you want a copy, you can do

```
int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting this code.

```
System.out.println(data instanceof Object);
```

You'll see output:

```
true
```

This is because `int[]` is a subclass of `Object`. Simply, `copy` now points to the same array that data points to.

Comment: This was interesting and helpful! Thank you. What else could you apply this too?